# Perl code that breaks a line after fixed number of columns

Tags: formatting, perl

Here is a simple program that I created to print a file by breaking it after a fixed number of columns. I feel it can be optimized but not sure how. Any feedback is great.

```
#This is a simple program that takes a file and the limits the columns length to
#the number passed in as second argument
if ($#ARGV < 1) {
   printf("Usage: perl %s <name of the input file> <column length>\n", $0);
   exit(-1);
}
$file=$ARGV[0];
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");
$LINE_LENGTH = $ARGV[1];
$count = 0;
foreach $line (<INFO>)  {
    #print $line;
    if (length($line) <= $LINE_LENGTH) {
      printf("%s\n", $line);
    } else {
      $remaining_chars  = length ($line);
      $remaining_line = $line;
      while ($remaining_chars >= $LINE_LENGTH) {
          $cur_str = substr($remaining_line, 0, $LINE_LENGTH - 1 );
          printf("%s\n", $cur_str );
          $remaining_line = substr($remaining_line, $LINE_LENGTH - 1);
          $remaining_chars = $remaining_chars - length($cur_str);
      }
      printf("%s",$remaining_line );
    }
    if ($++counter == 2){
      last;
    }
}
printf("\n");
close(INFO);
```

Comment: See also [Text::Fold](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Fold) and [Text::Wrap](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Wrap)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure it can be optimized in a sense of better performance. It could be streamlined though. The initial test for `length($line) <= $LINE_LENGTH` is just redundant. Compare:

```
    while (length ($line) > LINE_LENGTH) {
        $prefix = substr($line, 0, $LINE_LENGTH - 1 );
        $line = substr($line, $LINE_LENGTH - 1);
        printf("%s\n", $prefix);
    }
    printf("%s",$line );
```

PS: I am not familiar with perl enough. If there is a `split at position` function, you may use it instead of calling `substr` twice.

Answer (score 2):

`use strict;`

^^^ always.

You will be saved from embarassing things, like this:

> ```
> if ($++counter == 2){
>   last;
> }
> ```

Seriously, what is that? ;-)

With perl it's often best to put required arguments first, and then use `ARGV` magic to handle the input files. In other words, put the column width first, and then the input files... The `ARGV` magic is powerful, it will read all the files given on the commandline, or, read the STDIN if no files are given. By shifting the column width off the `@ARGV` you can let the magic do its thing.

`chomp` is another nice trick, it removes any trailing newlines, if any.

The lines can be printed with brute-force substrings in a while loop then.

I would write your code as:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $cols = shift @ARGV;
# Set a default, if empty
$cols ||= 80;

while (my $line = <>) {
    chomp $line;
    while (length($line) > $cols) {
        print substr($line, 0, $cols) . "\n";
        $line = substr($line, $cols);
    }
    print $line . "\n";
}
```

Note, assuming this is saved as a file called "narrow", then this can now be called in many ways:

- `narrow 80 *.java`
- `curl http://example.com | narrow`
- `curl http://example.com | narrow 120`
- etc.

Comment: `for my $line (<>)` => `while (my $line = <>)`

Comment: @mpapec - hmm.. i should run things before answering.... checking now.

Comment: `while` doesn't slurp a whole file into memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585341/whats-the-difference-between-iterating-over-a-file-with-foreach-or-while-in-per

Comment: @mpapec - yeah, and even the for should have been a foreach, I think, without the slurp (actually, not so much a slurp, but a non-scalar context).

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression instead of `substr()`,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV != 2) {
   die("Usage: perl $0 <name of the input file> <column length>\n");
}    
my ($file, $LINE_LENGTH) = @ARGV;

open(my $INFO, "<", $file) or die($!);
my $count = 0;
while (my $line = <$INFO>)  {

    print $1, "\n" while $line =~ /( .{1,$LINE_LENGTH} )/xg;

    # ...
    if (++$count == 2) {
      last;
    }
}
print "\n";
close($INFO);
```